# How to fix the SyntaxError: can't assign to literal on Python

Tags: python, function, factorial

I am a complete beginner on Python, so while learning the Python functions.

I am trying to write a function to compute factorial.

But I keep getting this one error:
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal

I have tried to put a variable but nothing works, but what do I know, I am only a beginner. Your help would be highly appreciated.

```
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    if(n==0 | n==1):
        return 1

    else:
        for 2 in n:
            result = n* factorial(n-1)
        return result

factorial(5)
```

Comment: You cannot use `for 2 in n:` you can use `for x in n:` as 2 is integer and cannot assigned as variable.

Comment: `for 2 in n:` that means you want to do `2 = next(iter_n)` (and so on).

Answer (score 1):

read up on loops, your for loop does not really make sense. What you are looking for is something like this

```
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    if(n==0 | n==1):
        return 1

    else:
        for i in range(1, n):
            result = n* factorial(n-1)
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

`for 2 in n`. This is not how loops work. You're assigning something to the literal `2` which you can't do. You probably want something like `for n in range(2):`
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

```
if(n==0 | n==1)
```

`|` does not mean `or` in Python, it is a bitwise OR. The correct syntax is

```
if(n==0 or n==1)
```

https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: Wasn't really the problem though

Comment: @Skirrebattie I reread, and realised what the real problem here was